# Mongodb Node JS serverStatus always returns false

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongo and am messing around with the admin serverStatus.  For me, it always returns false when I am expecting an object.  I'm running mongod with auth enabled.  Are there specific user privs that are required?  I can't find much documentation other than what is supplied by the API docs from the nodejs drivers or the mongodb manual.

MonogDB 3.4
NodeJS drivers 2.2

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/test?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=test', function(err, db) {
  var adminDB = db.admin();
  adminDB.serverStatus(function(err, status) {
    console.log(status);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  With auth enabled databases you need to grant a role to the executing user with the serverStatus action.

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "mongostatRole",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "serverStatus" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```